# Use recursion in python to combine lists of variable sizes

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, recursion, iteration

I have a problem with a problem, that got a bit problematic as problems go.

situation:

I need to combine items in list(s) of variable sizes, with variable sized elements, store those combinations and then iterate through them. I tried itertools, but I get too many combinations, which I have no idea how to properly "clean".
I get correct combinations by just creating as many for loops as the number of "op" elements in the input list is.

example:
NOTE: number of "op" dictionaries may vary! Ignore values as such, what matters is, I use list of "op" dictionaries to basically get all custom controls in Nuke GUI element called NoOp node. I need to iterate through each of the controls for each value, making all possible combinations:

```
for option1 in op1["options"]:
    for option2 in op2["options"]:
        for option3 in op3["options"]:
            print op1["control"], option1, op2["control"], option2,   op3["control"], option3
```

For now i am just trying to get my head around how to define the base case :/

```
def getCombos(controls, n = 0):
        #combos = []
        if n == 0:
            #return [(control["control"], option) for control in controls for option in control["options"]]
            return [(item["control"], option) for item in controls for option in item["options"]]
        else:
            for control in controls:
                return(getCombos(controls, n-1))
                n -= 1


op1 = {"control": "Material", "options": ["Glass", "Metal", "Wood"]}
op2 = {"control": "Base",
       "options": ["Chrome", "Brass", "Bronce", "Gold", "Nickel", "Red Gold"]}
op3 = {"control": "Color", "options": ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Cyan", "SomeWonderfulNewColor"]}


controls = [op1, op2, op3]
#NOTE: number of elements (dict) in list controls may vary!

for i,combo in enumerate(getCombos(controls, n=len(controls))):
    print i, combo
```

ATM this script just recursively prints the controls

How do I use recursion for this case, and more importantly, should I use recursion at all, and if yes, how do I approach such a case and break it down to it's components?
Cheers,

Comment: While I like the introduction, the post lacks a [MCVE] with concrete sample data. Input, expected output and wrong output from your current approach.

Comment: What sort of "combinations" do you want? Have you tried `itertools.product(opt1["options"], opt2["options"], ...)`?

Comment: maybe I really should put tuples in previous example: 

for option1 in op1["options"]:
    for option2 in op2["options"]:
        for option3 in op3["options"]:
            print (op1["control"], option1), (op2["control"], option2),   (op3["control"], option3)

I will try the solutions already posted, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to get all the combination of options, you should use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> list(itertools.product(op1["options"], op2["options"], op3["options"]))
[('Glass', 'Chrome', 'Red'),
 ('Glass', 'Chrome', 'Blue'),
 ('Glass', 'Chrome', 'Green'),
 ...
 ('Wood', 'Red Gold', 'Cyan'),
 ('Wood', 'Red Gold', 'SomeWonderfulNewColor')]
```

If you want to combine those with the respective `control`, you could write a helper function to get the pairs, then get the `product` of those:

```
>>> pairs = lambda op: [(op["control"], o) for o in op["options"]]
>>> pairs(op1)
[('Material', 'Glass'), ('Material', 'Metal'), ('Material', 'Wood')]

>>> list(itertools.product(*map(pairs, (op1, op2, op3))))
[(('Material', 'Glass'), ('Base', 'Chrome'), ('Color', 'Red')),
 (('Material', 'Glass'), ('Base', 'Chrome'), ('Color', 'Blue')),
 (('Material', 'Glass'), ('Base', 'Chrome'), ('Color', 'Green')),
 ...
 (('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Cyan')),
 (('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'SomeWonderfulNewColor'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you should use recursion:

```
def print_all(controls, idx, combination):
    if idx == len(controls):
        print(combination)
        return

    for x in controls[idx]['options']:
        print_all(controls, idx+1, combination + " " + controls[idx]['control'] + " " + str(x))


op1 = {"control": "Material", "options": ["Glass", "Metal", "Wood"]}
op2 = {"control": "Base",
   "options": ["Chrome", "Brass", "Bronce", "Gold", "Nickel", "Red Gold"]}
op3 = {"control": "Color", "options": ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Cyan", "SomeWonderfulNewColor"]}
op4 = {"control": "year", "options": [2010, 2020]}

controls = [op1, op2, op3, op4]

print_all(controls, 0, "")
```

Comment: Copy the code in a file, correct the indentation and run it.

Comment: This solution looks very elegant to me, how can I change the output from strings to pairs and store those in a list for further use?

Comment: @Klemen would you tell me what those pairs look like?

Comment: ('Material', 'Glass'), ('Base', 'Chrome'), ('Color', 'Red')),
('Material', 'Glass'), ('Base', 'Chrome'), ('Color', 'Blue')),
('Material', 'Glass'), ('Base', 'Chrome'), ('Color', 'Green')),
..
('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Cyan')),
('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'SomeWonderfulNewColor'))

Comment: [
[('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Red'), ('year', '2020')],
[('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Blue'), ('year', '2010')],
[('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Blue'), ('year', '2020')]
] 
???

Comment: A list of lists, where each list is a combination and each member of the inner list is a tuple?

Comment: more like: [(('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Red')), (('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'Cyan')), (('Material', 'Wood'), ('Base', 'Red Gold'), ('Color', 'SomeWonderfulNewColor')) ]

In the end, i need the function to generate a list of tuples containing pairs, so I can assign each control's state/value. example: node[control].setValue(value) where control and value correspond to pair.
If you, or anybody else has more elegant solution, i am more than happy to hear it. 
Thank you

Comment: @tobias_k, i am sorry m8, yes, your code does exactly what I want, thank you. I was just wondering how to approach the problem using recursions.

Comment: @Klemen No problem; I understood your question as "is recursion the right way for this?".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to print all combinations in three steps:

1. Go from `{control: control_val, options: options_vals}` to `{control_val: options_vals}`. This is done by the `from_record` function.
2. Transform `{control_val: options_vals}` to a list of `[(control_val, options_val)]`. This is done by `iter_dict`.
3. Take a product of such lists across all different op's.
4. Format and print. 3 and 4 are handled by `print_combinations`.

---

```
from itertools import product


def from_record(dct):
    return {dct["control"]: dct["options"]}


def iter_dict(dct):
    yield from ((k, v) for k, vs in dct.items() for v in vs)


def print_combinations(dcts):
    for item in product(*(iter_dict(from_record(dct)) for dct in dcts)):
        print(", ".join(["{}: {}".format(*t) for t in item]))


op1 = {"control": "Material", "options": ["Glass", "Metal", "Wood"]}
op2 = {
    "control": "Base",
    "options": ["Chrome", "Brass", "Bronce", "Gold", "Nickel", "Red Gold"],
}
op3 = {
    "control": "Color",
    "options": ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Cyan", "SomeWonderfulNewColor"],
}

print_combinations([op1, op2, op3])

# e.g.
# Material: Glass, Base: Chrome, Color: Red
# Material: Glass, Base: Chrome, Color: Blue
# Material: Glass, Base: Chrome, Color: Green
# Material: Glass, Base: Chrome, Color: Cyan
# Material: Glass, Base: Chrome, Color: SomeWonderfulNewColor
```

---

Alternatively, all possible combinations may be listed more compactly by combining different op dicts:

```
res = dict()
ops = [op1, op2, op3]
for op in ops:
    res.update(from_record(op))


# {'Base': ['Chrome', 'Brass', 'Bronce', 'Gold', 'Nickel', 'Red Gold'],
 # 'Color': ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Cyan', 'SomeWonderfulNewColor'],
 # 'Material': ['Glass', 'Metal', 'Wood']}
```

Comment: Makes sense. You should probably add an example of what you want in the question.